# GetLocation in Array in Java

Tags: java

Hello i want to getLocation in Array. I try to make this with a loop but it isn't workinm. Someone know how do fixed it? Thanks for help!

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;



 public class Clicker {


public static void main (String[] args) {




 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     PointerInfo inf = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
     Point[i] p = inf.getLocation()[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here `Point[i] p = inf.getLocation()[i];`?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Point[] p = new Point[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            PointerInfo inf = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            p[i] = inf.getLocation();
    }
```